# React Storybook not displaying SVG icons

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, storybook

I am not able to see the SVG icons in Storybook. I am new to front-end development so not sure what I am doing wrong. I referred to this article `https://medium.com/@derek_19900/config-storybook-4-to-use-svgr-webpack-plugin-22cb1152f004`. Here is file `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

const pathToInlineSvg = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/images/icons');

module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {

  const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test.test('.svg'));
  fileLoaderRule.exclude = pathToInlineSvg;

  config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (rule.exclude && rule.test.test('styles.scss')) {
      rule.use = rule.use.map(use => {
        if (use && use.loader && use.loader.indexOf('sass-loader') !== -1) {
          use.options.data = `
            @import "@/assets/styles/theme.scss";
            @import "@/assets/styles/fonts.scss";
          `;
        }
        return use;
      });
    }
    return rule;
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
      presets: [['react-app', { flow: false, typescript: true }]],
    },
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(jsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@salesforce/babel-preset-design-system-react"],
    },
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: pathToInlineSvg,
    use: [{loader: '@svgr/webpack',
              options: {
                icon: true,
              },
          }
    ],
  });

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx', '.svg');
  config.resolve.alias['@'] = rootDir;

  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

SVGs are not loading into Storybook in your setup because Storybook’s default webpack config already has a `.svg` loader, and is using `file-loader`.

See [Line 65 - Line 68 of Storybook base-webpack.config.js](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/lib/core/src/server/preview/base-webpack.config.js#L65-L68)

If you want to use `@svgr/webpack` loader, you need to [write a custom webpack config](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#full-control-mode) so that the `@svgr/webpack` loader rule is before the `file-loader`.

This webpack config rule adds the `@svgr/webpack` loader before any other asset loaders:

```js
  // Add SVGR Loader
  // ========================================================
  // Remove svg rules from existing webpack rule
  const assetRule = config.module.rules.find(({ test }) => test.test('.svg'));

  const assetLoader = {
    loader: assetRule.loader,
    options: assetRule.options || assetRule.query,
  };

  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack', assetLoader],
  });
```

You can see a complete `webpack.config.js` in this [Gatsby starter (Gatsby + TypeScript + Emotion + Storybook)](https://github.com/duncanleung/gatsby-typescript-emotion-storybook/blob/master/.storybook/webpack.config.js#L55-L68)

Comment: I've also seen your official blog post about this, but for some reason this still doesn't work

Comment: Where did the config come from over here? This doesn't work

Comment: Any reason why would you keep the old assetLoader for svg? Why not just unshift the `@svgr/webpack` alone ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [storybook-preset-inline-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-preset-inline-svg).

Storybook has loaders configured that conflict with what you define in your custom Webpack configuration, so if you do not override those then your custom rules will not work.

Here's a basic way to override some of the default SVG loaders (adjust to your needs):

```
config.module.rules = [
  ...config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (/svg/.test(rule.test)) {
      // Silence the Storybook loaders for SVG files
      return { ...rule, exclude: /\.svg$/i }
    }

    return rule
  }),
  // Add your custom SVG loader
  {
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    use: ['whatever-loader-you-want']
  }
]
```

Depending on your setup you may want to look into the [Storybook preset API for Webpack](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/addons/writing-presets#webpack) to override loaders for the manager entries too.

Comment: I have tried to use this code but the syntax does not seems right. It's not working at least for me (the syntax of the new rule)

Comment: Looks like there was a missing closing parenthesis and the original non-svg rules were not returned from `map`. @AntonioGamizDelgado you can try again after my edits or grab the npm package.

Comment: Overriding the default loader like this worked for me! I tried a few other options that were a little more prescriptive or tried to mix the Storybook default config with your own options, and they were all throwing errors.

Didn't use `storybook-preset-inline-svg` though, just used my project's own solution after silencing the Storybook rule and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In  the newest storybook here's the solution:
Set your script on `package.json` to

```
"scripts": {
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 --no-dll -s ./public",
}
```

Comment: Don't work with storybook 6.3.0 =(

Comment: Does not work in `6.4.14` either.

Comment: Does not work in 6.4.19 either.

Comment: Tried, but does not work.